# Adobe AIR Multiple Window Issue

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have an AIR application with muti level windows. Application A opens Window B which has subwindow C. Window B is listening for the system manager's Sandbox Event( Mouse Down Somewhere) to close itself.

```
systemManager.addEventListener(SandboxMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_SOMEWHERE)
```

But this event is dispatched when we click on the app (A) as well as the sub window(C). Is it possible to determine the origin of the sandbox event to prevent closing the window when click on its sub window. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.target property in the listener function to determine which window the mouse down event occurs.

Comment: yes, tried that, event.target and event.currentTarget is always pointing to the systemManager

Comment: You can add eventlistener to B Window for FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE  event. Here it will return the clicked window in the event.target

Comment: that event will not get triggered when you click outside of the window

Comment: If your window is popup then it will definitely be fired.

Comment: actually our situation is different. Each window is on its own stage and sandbox. Thanks for your help!